# HTML/CSS : nested list needs to be displayed elsewhere / using mother div instead of mother element for position orientation

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have a nested list for a navigation

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2
    <ul>
      <li>item 2.1</li>
      <li>item 2.2</li>
      <li>item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to display the top level (item1, 2 & 3) at the top right of the page in a horizontal line. The submenu should be displayed as a list on the left side of the page.
I can not change the HTML aparently.

So how do i get the sublevel out of there?
Using position:absolute it will use the upper level for orientation wich will change depending on the width of the main level. 
I need it to use the mother div for orientation so i can place it on the right side of the page.
Is this even possible?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @RohitAzad sweet, but not what i want. I want the subnavigation to be somewhere completely different on the page, not related to the main navigation :(

Comment: "I need it to use the mother div for orientation so i can place it on the right side of the page." what you mean in there?

Comment: @RohitAzad You don't seem to understand: The Subnavigation has to be completely independent from the main navigation. Completely independent. Not attatched. Positioned in reference to the mother div, not the mother ul element. You get me?

Comment: @Andresch Serj: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/J7phH/)

**CSS:**

```
ul { float: right; }
ul li { float: left; padding: 0 20px;  }
ul li ul { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display:none; }
ul li ul li { float: none; }
ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```